# Why doesn't the following piece of jquery run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm trying to fetch some html with jquery/ajax,  load it into a div, then call the show method with the blind effect on it.  But I can't figure out what's going wrong for the life of me.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { // The relevant jQuery
    $("#effect").hide(); // Make sure the div I'm going to show is not visible first off.
    $("#foo").click(function(){  // foo is a button
        $.ajax({url:"after.html", success:function(result){ // Grab the html I want.  (just an <h1> tag)
            $("#effect").html(result).show("blind", {direction: "horizontal"}, 400); // When I comment out this line it works, but with the exception of the id's to select it's exactly the same as in another working page.
            alert("loaded after.html...");
        }});
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="narrow">
   <p><input type="submit" id="foo"/></p>
</div>


<div id="effect" style="background-color:white; float:right; height:400px; width:400px;">
</div>
```

Without calling the `$("#effect").html(result).show("blind", {direction: "horizontal"}, 400);` line, everything runs fine.  However, with that line it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` in the console. (Chrome)

I was using [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-blind.htm) page as a reference when I ran into this problem.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have jQuery UI loaded because regular jQuery doesn't have a `.show()` that takes those arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Blind effect is a part of JQueryUI. In the tutorial you shared, you can see that code. Are you sure that something like `jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js` is referenced on your page as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Contents of my <header></header> :



` <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: @Nick No, $.ajax method is part of core JQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @alex0112 could you please share jsfiddle for it?

Comment: @cebirci My mistake, I just realised.

Comment: @cebirci Sure.  Hang on.

Comment: Also, I'm including the '<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>' found on the jQuery UI website in the demo.  So I don't think that's the problem.  In case anyone was still looking at that.

Comment: @cebirci  So, I've never actually made a jsfiddle before.  This might be a bit.  How do I include multiple html files?  (e.g. the one ajax has to load)

Comment: I am also trying to find the problem. Wait please.

Comment: I made a test page for you, with your codes. And I think it works: http://www.fenerbahcetransfer.com/hctest/t1.html

Comment: If you are testing it on your local, it can be disallowed to make a ajax request (XMLHttpRequest) to your after.html file.